# AngularJS create deferred function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I'm new to angularJS and still have some difficulties with promises... I have the following function:

```
   removeMultipleAttachments: function(docid, rev, attachmentIDs) {

        var p = $q.when();
        angular.forEach(attachments, function(file, index) {
            return p.then(function (formerRes) {
                return pouch.removeAttachment(docid, attachmentIDs[index], rev);
            }).then(function(res) {
                rev = res.rev;
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });
        })
   }
```

and would like to be able to call it and use a .then() with the responses when it finishes such as:

```
removeMultipleAttachments(mydocID, myRev, myAttachments).then(function(responses){ ---is called only when done ---  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `$q.when()`  creates an empty resolved promise

What you're trying to do is chain completions. You're almost there, the problem is that you're returning in the `forEach` instead of chaining.

Try:

```
removeMultipleAttachments: function(docid, rev, attachmentIDs) {

        var p = $q.when();
        var retvals = [];
        angular.forEach(attachments, function(file, index) {
            p = p.then(function (formerRes) { // NOTE THE ASSIGNMENT HERE
                return pouch.removeAttachment(docid, attachmentIDs[index], rev);
            }).then(function(res) {
                retvals.push(res);
                rev = res.rev;
                $rootScope.$apply(); // You really don't need the apply here
            });
        })
        return p.then(function(){ return retvals; }); // AND THE RETURN HERE
   }
```

Note this will execute *sequentially*, one promise at a time. If you want to execute all the requests at once, you can use `$q.all`:

```
removeMultipleAttachments: function(docid, rev, attachmentIDs) {
    var p = $q.when();
    return $q.all(attachments.map(function(file,index){ 
        // not sure what to do with the res.rev = rev part
        return pouch.removeAttachment(docid,attachmentIDs[index], rev);
    });
}
```

Comment: OK I tested this solution but the response inside the then() is undifined... is it possible to get an array of reponses or an agregate?

Comment: @ncohen yes, it is. For example my `$q.all` version does this, you did not specify you wanted the return values. Let me make a quick edit for that. **update** ok I've made a quick edit.

Comment: I get 'res is not defined' :( Isn't retvals that I should return?

Comment: Finally... got it! you're just missing the 's' for retvals for the returned variable

Comment: @ncohen I was just umm, testing your awareness :P Thanks for spotting that.